# ember action triggered when press enter

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I have this form write in ember using bootstrap framework.
I want when keypress enter to catch the primary button, but the action cancel triggered.

```
<form {{action 'create' on="submit"}} class="form-horizontal form-bordered formaddObject">

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="leftColCampaignType">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label labelFormCampaign addObject">Campaign's name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="rightColCampaignType">
                {{input value=campaign_name id="campaign_name" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control"}}
                <div class="transitionbuttonsinCampsettings transitionbuttonsinAddObject">
                    <button class="btn btn-default"{{action 'cancel'}} style="background-color: #E2E2E2;">Cancel</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="background-color:#ffa019!important; border:none;">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `type="button"` to your Cancel button it is not going to trigger form submission when pressing enter.

So your Cancel button look something like:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"{{action 'cancel'}} style="background-color: #E2E2E2;">Cancel</button>`

Here's a full working example, check out the console logs coming from the route actions:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pipivibedo/1/edit?html,js,console,output